# Find gaps in table with non-time-based start and end columns

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I need to find the gaps in consecutive data points based on double precision start and end columns.

For simplicity let's call them **startPoint** and **endPoint** which track a position in space on a line. The difference between the endPoint and the startPoint would denominate a distance. Over this "distance" particular force/effect signal values are captured and based on the values a **state** is stored on the table. Each row has a unique **id** identifier.

Thus, the table looks like the following:

```
| id | startPoint | endPoint | state    |
|----|------------|----------|----------|
| 1  | 0.0        | 5.8      | Active   |
| 2  | 5.8        | 7.1      | Inactive |
| 3  | 7.5        | 10.2     | Inactive |
| 4  | 10.2       | 11.3     | Inactive |
| 5  | 11.6       | 12.1     | Active   |
```

I have struggled to come up with a query that works in **PostgresSQL** that yields the following result:

```
| startGap   | endGap   |
|------------|----------|
| 7.1        | 7.5      |
| 11.3       | 11.6     |
```

It is clear to me all I have to do is compare the previous endPoint to the following startPoint but I have had no luck thus far.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why the MySQL tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the window function [`lead()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html):

```
with my_table(id, startpoint, endpoint, state) as (
values
    (1, 0.0, 5.8, 'Active'),
    (2, 5.8, 7.1, 'Inactive'),
    (3, 7.5, 10.2, 'Inactive'),
    (4, 10.2, 11.3, 'Inactive'),
    (5, 11.6, 12.1, 'Active')
)

select *
from (
    select endpoint as startgap, lead(startpoint) over (order by startpoint) as endgap
    from my_table
    ) s
where startgap <> endgap;

 startgap | endgap 
----------+--------
      7.1 |    7.5
     11.3 |   11.6
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested using SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2851c3/2/0  (I obviously thought this was mySQL for some reason)

Likely not the most efficient as it has to run the subquery for each record in A less the max...

Essentially this does a LEFT OUTER self join to get the end point from a and start point from B and where a match in the join isn't found we identified the endpoint which becomes the startgap. and then we use a subquery to find the min startpoint above that value

We exclude the last record with the highest startpoint as we know there's no point to look for a gap after the last record.

This does assume no overlap of data.

```
SELECT A.EndPoint as StartGap
     , (SELECT min(StartPoint) 
        FROM sqlfoo 
        WHERE StartPoint > A.EndPoint) as EndGap
FROM sqlfoo A
LEFT JOIN sqlfoo B 
 on A.EndPoint = B.StartPoint
WHERE B.StartPoint is null
  and A.StartPoint <> (SELECT max(startPoint) FROM sqlfoo)
```

This identifes the max start

Comment: well the reason is the tag was mysql :/